# Stay on same page if condition met in vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am working on a vue app. I have the following code in my router.js file. The if condition mentioned on the bold, in the case I want the user to stay on the same page even if the user clicks on any other link on the same page. Please help me how to do that.

```
router.beforeEach(function(to, from, next) {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    axios.get('/verification.json')
    axios.get('/agent.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        if (to.path === '/sign-up' || to.path === '/change-password') {
          next('/');
          return;
        }
        **if ((from.path === '/agencies' || to.path.match(/profile/agencies/)) && response.data.verified === 'yes' && response.data.category === "C" ) {
          *Stay on the same page.*
        }
        next();**
      })
      .catch(function() {
        if (to.path.match(/profile/agencies/)) {
          next('/');
          return;
        }
        next();
      });
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Next(false) https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `next(false)` in your conditional block to abort navigation. You can found more info about `next` [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards).

```
if ((from.path === '/agencies' || to.path.match(/profile/agencies/)) && response.data.verified === 'yes' && response.data.category === "C" ) {
      //Stay on the same page
      next(false);
}
```

You can also use `next(error)` instead of `next(false)` in combination with `router.onError(callback)` to show some error.